# Some problems to show 4 <li> elements in two columns

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float

I am finding some difficulties to do the following thing using HTML and CSS.

I have this page: http://www.onofri.org/example/example4/

As you can see there is a box having title "CREATING POLICY FRAMEWORK FOR PROMOTING INVESTMENT" created by the `#policyFrameworkBox div`

In this box I have an unordered list with 4 `<li>` elements inside it having `class="floattedList"`

I want group this `li` element in two columns:

the first and the second `li` element on a single row and the third and the fourth `li` on a second row.

To do it I was trying to do the following operation:

```
#policyFrameworkBox li{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #004673;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

In practice I try to float the `li` element as to be next to one another and I set the width to 50% so two `li` elements occupy the entire space so go head and see the others two `li` elements in the second row.

But don't work and the `li` elements still show in column

Why? What have I to do to show the first `li` next to the second `li` on the first line and the third `li` next to the fourth `li` on the second line?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving it a 46% width.

With the 2% of padding-left and the 2% of padding-right, the total makes 50%, actually are 54% ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see them on the same row is width.
50% + 4% padding and there is no enough space for 2 on the same line.
so change width to < 48%.

however this will not be the full solution, the first 2 items will be on same line and not on same row as you want, to fix this you could rearrange the markup, or split into 2 lists.